# How to connect "TreeListControl" to the database table "Access" with the help of the designer?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

VS 2017
DEVEXPRES 17.2
Wpf

Table
[image]
The Access file is located
c:\test\visualStudio\csharp\prb\00_DB\dbAccessTest.accdb

If I correctly understood, then the way should be written here (see screen)
[image]

I get a mistake
"Invalid property path syntax."
[image]
I found nothing in the documentation.

**Question.**
How to connect "TreeListControl" to the database table "Access" with the help of the designer?

Comment: You are binding to the whole database! How is WPF supposed to know which table in the DB you are referring to?

Comment: @EMett Where and how to register the table?
I can not find the documentation how to do this